# JQuery Selectable dragging mouse box now shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/ks10hwj4/.
It consists of a list

```
<ul class="files-list list-group items-list ui-selectable" style="min-height:200px;">
```

with each element being like

```
<li class="file-item0 list-group-item list-group-item-action ui-widget-content ui-selectee ui-selected">
<div class="row ui-selectee active ui-selected">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 vertical-align ui-selectee active ui-selected">
        a folder
    </div>
</div>
```

then I call the selectable function telling it to modify the active class of bootstrap when selected

```
$('.files-list').selectable({
    cancel: ".ui-splitselect-item .ui-splitselect-handle-drag",
    selecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selecting).addClass('active');
    },
    unselecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselecting).removeClass('active');
    },
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass('active');
    },
    unselected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselected).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

It works perfectly but it does not show the box when I select the files. I mean, I can't see the box the mouse is generating while clicking and moving around. What could be the problem?

Comment: What box? Can you please be more clear?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930585/jquery-ui-selectable-without-selection-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the jQuery-ui css file. Try adding the css below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

UPDATE:

Changing the color of the selected box can be done by adding some css to your own css file. The '!important' overwrites the original color in the jQuery-ui.css.

```
.ui-selected {
    background: #00b448 !important;
}
```

Comment: exactly that! Thank you so much! How can i change the color of it btw?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to give you a heads up on how to change the color.